# Automatic opening of VPN connection

Tags: android

On Android we'd like to use a VPN when the user is connected to the cell-network.

But the problem is that the VPN connection does not automatically open when switching between WiFi and cell-network.

It also doesn't automatically connect when the device is rebooted.

IS There any potential way of automatically opening a VPN connection when switching between WiFi and cell-network and also when the device reboots.

We'd need this for Android Gingerbread & Ice Cream Sandwich.

The VPN open when the users switches between WiFi and the cell-network.

Comment: Are you asking for some code snippets of switching on VPN, or you are looking for apps, that can do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. When network changes:

add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in your manifest. Set up a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for the action `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. In this receiver, get an instance of `ConnectivityManager` using `Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);` and check if network is connected. If so, you can go on and start your vpn login.

1. On reboot:

add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` to manifest. Set up a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for the action `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Here you can proceed to establish your vpn connection.

Comment: The network change receiver will be activated as soon as there is a network change - including if you switch off data/wifi or move from wifi to data. When the network changes, you can do the code to deal with it - relogin, notify the user, or whatever.

Comment: There is a caveat in ICS and above - applications won't receive the system broadcasts such as `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` unless the user has manually opened the app atleast once after installation, due to security considerations. This shouldn't be a problem because I'm guessing your user will have to open the app to configure the username, password, certificates, etc